# Calling Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration routines from WMI com object

Tags: python

Thanks in advance for help. I am trying to set the ip address of a network interface using win32com module and unable to do so. I have tried searching a lot but wasn't able to get a answer for the issue. Here is the code I am running :

```
import win32com.client 
obj  = win32com.client.Dispatch("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator") 
wmobj = obj.ConnectServer("localhost","root\cimv2")
nobj = wmobj.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration")
for n in nobj:
    print n.Caption
    n.SetMTU('9000')
```

When I run this code it errors out with following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 3, in <module>
    n.SetMTU('9000')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 505, in __getattr__
    ret = self._oleobj_.Invoke(retEntry.dispid,0,invoke_type,1)
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'SWbemObjectEx', u'Invalid method ', None, 0, -2147217362), None)
```

I did some more debugging and found that I can access any variables of `Win32Networking` class but whenever I try to call any method of the class it returns me this same error.

Comment: I tried with Tim golden WMI module also and ended up with same error. Probably missing something basic common. Following is the code i tried with WMI module.                                     import wmi
netobj = wmi.WMI().Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration( IPEnabled=True )
for a in netobj:
    print a.caption
    print a.MACAddress
    print a.mtu
    print a.ipaddress
    a.setipaddress('')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have much experience using `win32com`, but probably the `SetMTU` method isn't implemented. According to the MSDN docs for the [Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394217), the method is "not supported". It fails for me in XP.

Note that with win32com, just accessing an attribute can invoke it:

```
>>> import win32com.client
>>> wmobj = obj.ConnectServer("localhost","root\cimv2")
>>> nobj = wmobj.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration")
>>> n = nobj[10]  #my wireless interface
>>> n.ReleaseDHCPLease  #invoked
0
>>> n.RenewDHCPLease
0
```

Trying to call it normally will end up attempting to call the integer return value, which raises a `TypeError`. However, you can first wrap such a method to make it a normal Python call:

```
>>> n._FlagAsMethod('ReleaseDHCPLease')
>>> n._FlagAsMethod('RenewDHCPLease')
>>> n.ReleaseDHCPLease()
0
>>> n.RenewDHCPLease()
0
```

---

Edit:

In the user contributions area of the page linked above, search for a list of static methods, which have to be accessed from the class, including `SetMTU`. Here's how to get the class:

```
>>> NetAdapterConfig = wmobj.Get("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration")
>>> NetAdapterConfig._FlagAsMethod('SetMTU')
```

See [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393463) for the meaning of the return value. Though I don't really understand what this method does in a static context.

---

Here's an example of using the standard library's `winreg` to update the registry:

```
import winreg

nid = n.SettingID
MTU = 1500

path = r'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\TCPIP\Parameters\Interfaces\\'+ nid 
sam = winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS
adapter = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, path, 0, sam)
winreg.SetValueEx(adapter, 'MTU', None, winreg.REG_DWORD, MTU)
```

Comment: Still fails with following error :     >>> n._FlagAsMethod('EnableStatic')                                       >>> n.EnableStatic('10.193.184.215','255.255.255.0')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#31>", line 1, in <module>
    n.EnableStatic('10.193.184.215','255.255.255.0')
  File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 2, in EnableStatic
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'SWbemObjectEx', u'Type mismatch ', None, 0, -2147217403), None)

Comment: @Rohit: `EnableStatic` expects arrays. You can use either tuples or lists. Try `n.EnableStatic(['10.193.184.215'], ['255.255.255.0'])`.

Comment: SetMTU still fails with Invalid Method error. I am running on Windows 2008R2 there it is supported. Is it possible to list all the method from a com object

Comment: Error : >>> n._FlagAsMethod('SetMTU')
>>> n.SetMTU(2000)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#50>", line 1, in <module>
    n.SetMTU(2000)
  File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 2, in SetMTU
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'SWbemObjectEx', u'Invalid method ', None, 0, -2147217362), None)

Comment: This Works, but the problem is it sets for all present Network cards in system. I am in need to search a specific adapter and then change parameters. This is becoming too hectic, can you please suggest some easy way of configuring Network adapters on Windows machine using Python.

Comment: @Rohit: You can use `winreg`(`_winreg` in Python 2.x) to update the registry. `n.SettingID` is the key for the adapter in the list of adapter settings at `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\TCPIP\Parameters\Interfaces`.

Answer (score 1):

I met the similar problem, and find a way to invoke these methods of Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration object. Here I didn't use these methods directly, but wrap all input parameters into a SpawnInstance_. It seems wired but worked.

```
import win32com.client
objLocator = win32com.client.Dispatch("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
objService = objLocator.ConnectServer(".","root\cimv2")
nobj = objService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration Where IPEnabled = True")
obj = nobj[0]

## here is the strange part. 
obj_method = obj.Methods_("SetWINSServer")
obj_in_param = obj_method.inParameters.SpawnInstance_()
obj_in_param.WINSPrimaryServer = "127.0.0.1"
obj_in_param.WINSSecondaryServer = "127.0.0.2"
#invoke the SetWINServer method, and it worked.
obj.ExecMethod_("SetWINSServer", obj_in_param)
```

Almost all these methods of Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration could be used like this.
However, "SetMTU" can't, maybe it's because "this method is not supported", I try it in Windows 2008R2 but get the same error.
It said SetMTU is not supported here.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393463(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just tried the `FlagAsMethod`

as suggested, for a `Win32_Process` class, example:

```
proc10 = GetObject(pos).ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process")[10]
proc10._FlagAsMethod('GetOwner')
proc10.GetOwner()
# >> 0
```

However, I am expecting `domain\user` etc. Moreover, I am also able to write

```
proc10.GetOwner(10,20,30)
```

but the effect is the same.

I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078570/how-to-set-process-priority-using-pywin32-and-wmi/12631794#12631794) a method working in my case. I was just wondering if the `SetMTU` received the correct value using the `_FlagAsMethod` tip.