# How to get Process Owner by Python using WMI?

Tags: python, windows, winapi, process, wmi

I tried to get some information about Process Owner, using WMI. I tried to run this script:

```
import win32com.client

process_wmi = set()
strComputer = "."
objWMIService = win32com.client.Dispatch("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
objSWbemServices = objWMIService.ConnectServer(strComputer,"root\cimv2")


process_list = objSWbemServices.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process")
for process in process:
    owner = process.GetOwner
    if owner != 0:
        print('Access denied')
    else:
        print('process: ',process.Name, 'PID: ', process.ProcessId, 'Owner: ', owner)
```

Of course, i get `owner = 0  (Successful Completion)`

When I tried to call `process.GetOwner()`, I get this error: `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`

How to use this method without errors? With what parameters or with what flags maybe?

I try to actualize and use this method,  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078570/how-to-set-process-priority-using-pywin32-and-wmi/12631794#12631794), but I can't convert code to my situation and get Process Owner. =(

Or may be someone know another method, how to get information about process owner. May be with WinApi methods?

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the `psutil` library. I was using the winapi, and wmi, but it's terribly slow :( `psutil` is much, much faster and gives you a convenient API for working with processes.

You can achieve the same thing like this:

```
import psutil
for process in psutil.get_process_list():
    try:
        print('Process: %s, PID: %s, Owner: %s' % (process.name, process.pid,
                                                   process.username))
    except psutil.AccessDenied:
        print('Access denied!')
```

And because only the username can give you Access denied you can in `except` do:

```
except psutil.AccessDenied:
    print('Process: %s, PID: %s, Owner: DENIED' % (process.name, process.pid)
```

If you can use only pywin32 and wmi then this will work:

```
import wmi
for i in wmi.WMI().Win32_Process():
    print('%s, %s, %s' % (i.Name, i.ProcessId, i.GetOwner()[2]))
```

Comment: Thank you, but I can use only WinApi or WMI in my project.

Comment: Updated the post, added wmi solution.

Answer (score 4):

The type error is because process_list from your code is an "unknown" COM object.  Try this:

```
import win32com  
from win32com.client import GetObject  
wmi = win32com.client.GetObject("winmgmts:")  
wmi = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch(wmi._oleobj_)  
#Now execute your query  
process = wmi.ExecQuery('select * from Win32_Process')  
proc = process[0]  
#Now I can do things like check properties  
print proc.Properties_('ProcessId').Value  
#Or use methods  
parms = proc.ExecMethod_('GetOwner')  
#Now I can do things with parms like  
username = parms.Properties_('User').Value
```

Parms will be a com object of type SWbemObject just like process and proc are.  It has other properties as well:  return value and domain.  I can poll it just like I did above for getting User from parms.  Hope this helps.

Sorry, adding after the fact:
the properties for parms in the code above specifically are User, Domain, and ReturnValue

Answer (score 0):

According to the accepted answer:

```
for process in list(psutil.process_iter()):
```

Because of:  [Deprecate psutil.get_process_list() #273](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/issues/273)